# jQuery find link that matches current page

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that is trying to find a link that matches the current url: `$item = $('ul#ui-ajax-tabs li a').attr('href', $(location).attr('pathname'));` but instead it changes all the links to the current url :P

Can anyone help me fix it. Cheers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use this query. Your code changes all `href` attributes of the selected links, rather than returning a selection of links with a matching `href` attribute:

```
$("a[href*='" + location.pathname + "']")
```

The `[href*=..]` selector returns a list of elements whose `href` attribute contains the current pathname.

Another method, return all elements whose `href` contains the current pathname. `prop()` is used instead of `attr()`, so that relative URLs are also correctly interpreted.

```
$item = $('ul#ui-ajax-tabs li a').filter(function(){
    return $(this).prop('href').indexOf(location.pathname) != -1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Where URL format might change in Production like ASP.NET :/ this might work better if you ignore the end slash of URLs.

```
$('.mdl-navigation').find("a").filter(function () {
  return this.href.replace(/\/+$/, '') === window.location.href.replace(/\/+$/, '');
}).addClass('current-active-page-url');
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your CSS selector `ul#ui-ajax-tabs li a` matches more than one thing. Try being more specific with your selector, such as `ul#ui-ajax-tabs li:first-child a`.